# AWS LexV2 messenger channel integration not sending requestAttributes

Tags: amazon-web-services, facebook, aws-lambda, messenger, amazon-lex

I am building a [AWS LexV2](https://console.aws.amazon.com/lexv2/home?region=us-east-1#welcome) chat bot that I want to integrate with Facebook Messenger via Channel Integration provided by LexV2. I am also using Lambda codehook to validate my inputs and fulfil my intents.

Following the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lexv2/latest/dg/deploying-messaging-platform.html), everything works as expected, except for one thing. When I log the `event` in my lambda function, `requestAttributes` field is missing from the object

My lambda function code:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    logger.error(event)
    return ...
```

When I send a message to my app/page on facebook, this is what is logged:

```
{
    "sessionId": "session-id",
    "inputTranscript": "Intent utterance",
    "interpretations":
    [
        {
            "intent":
            {
                "slots":
                {
                    "slot1": null,
                    "slot2": null
                },
                "confirmationState": "null",
                "name": "IntentName",
                "state": "InProgress"
            },
            "nluConfidence": 1.0
        },
        {
            "intent":
            {
                "slots":
                {},
                "confirmationState": "null",
                "name": "FallbackIntent",
                "state": "InProgress"
            }
        }
    ],
    "responseContentType": "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
    "invocationSource": "DialogCodeHook",
    "messageVersion": "1.0",
    "sessionState":
    {
        "intent":
        {
            "slots":
            {
                "slot1": null,
                "slot2": null
            },
            "confirmationState": "null",
            "name": "IntentName",
            "state": "InProgress"
        },
        "originatingRequestId": "req-id"
    },
    "bot":
    {
        "aliasId": "ALIASID",
        "aliasName": "AliasName",
        "name": "BotName",
        "version": "DRAFT",
        "localeId": "en_US",
        "id": "bot-id"
    },
    "inputMode": "Text"
}
```

As you can see, no `requestAttributes`.
What's weird to me is that when I do the same thing for LexV1 bot (same facebook page/messenger app), I get these fields, e.g.

```
    {
        "requestAttributes":
        {
            "x-amz-lex:facebook-page-id": "page-id",
            "x-amz-lex:channel-id": "channel-id",
            "x-amz-lex:webhook-endpoint-url": "webhook-endpoint",
            "x-amz-lex:accept-content-types": "PlainText",
            "x-amz-lex:user-id": "user-id",
            "x-amz-lex:channel-name": "channel-name",
            "x-amz-lex:channel-type": "Facebook"
        }
    }
```

If anyone has any tips (other than "switch to V1") I would be very grateful. Thanks :))

Notes:

1. Changed Python `None`s to `null`s to easier format JSON
2. Replaced IDs and names from the logs with generic-id-slash-names